# Draggable | Jquery UI. How to addClass on drag event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to create a slider so the user drags the slider ball and once the ball has been dragged it snaps to the end of the containment element and fires a callback function (think of IOS prior to 7 when you unlocked the screen by dragging the slider across, drag slider and screen unlocks). I thought the simplest way to do this would be to add a class which updates the slider ball's x-axis to the end of its container.

[image: Slide to unlock]

So I set up the element as draggable with the relevant containment element and axis and it drags perfectly along its container.

```
sliderBall.draggable({
          containment: $('div.slider-line'),
          axis: "x"
          });
```

Then I thought it would be as simple as binding 'addClass' to the 'drag' event like so:

```
sliderBall.on('drag',function() {
    $(this).addClass('slider-toggle');
});
```

The strange thing is that the selector is being recognised as an object and not a DOM element ?

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sliderBall" data-count="1">drag me!</div>
<div id="divDrop"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".sliderBall").draggable();

$("#divDrop").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {    
    ui.draggable.addClass("dropped")
  }
});
```

**[Online demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/j1kooLu3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem but decided to leave the question up incase anyone else has the same issues. The problem was the CSS class I was adding, for some reason the class was being added but it didn't want to change the X position of the slider ball unless I used 'transformX' in the class as opposed to 'left'.